# All cities in a given country Google-map

Tags: web-services, google-maps

Is it possible to use the services of Google-Map to get all the cities in a given country?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, all the Google services are limited. Try looking at [geonames](http://geonames.org), they have services that may do what you need or possibly you can download the data you need from there and serve it locally.

Disclaimer, it is not possible now.  Often if I make an absolute statement like this, the functionality becomes available later. You can try adding an [enhancement request to the issues list](http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/list?can=2&q=apitype%3aJavascript3%20type%3aEnhancement&sort=-stars&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Introduced%20Fixed%20Summary%20Internal%20Stars).

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the [Google Places API](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/)

Comment: How can I call this service on c #?